# Create color plots with custom_scalar in tensorboard

Tags: tensorflow, plugins, tensorboard

I started using the ***custom_scalars plugin*** in tensorboard and managed to plot multiple plots in a single graph using this interface.

However, I want these lines to be different colors - not just the standard orange color - in order to distinguish them better, in case I want to snapshot the graphs for documentation.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Ah, every color in each multi-line plot is currently associated with 1 run, so customizing colors is not yet possible unless every line is associated with a different run.

The different lines are differentiated by shape of marker though.