# Plot multiple graphs in one plot using Tensorboard

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

I am using Keras with Tensorflow backend. My work involves comparing the performances of several models such as Inception, VGG, Resnet etc on my dataset.
I would like to plot the training accuracies of several models in one graph. I am trying to do this in Tensorboard, but it is not working.

Is there a way of plotting multiple graphs in one plot using Tensorboard or is there some other way I can do this?

Thank you

Comment: See the answers to [TensorBoard - Plot training and validation losses on the same graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37146614).

Answer (score 33):

If you are using the [SummaryWriter](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensorboard.html?highlight=summarywriter#torch.utils.tensorboard.writer.SummaryWriter) from tensorboardX or pytorch 1.2, you have a method called [add_scalars](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensorboard.html?highlight=add_scalars#torch.utils.tensorboard.writer.SummaryWriter.add_scalars):

Call it like this:

```
my_summary_writer.add_scalars(f'loss/check_info', {
    'score': score[iteration],
    'score_nf': score_nf[iteration],
}, iteration)
```

And it will show up like this:

[image: tensorboard image]

---

Be careful that `add_scalars` will mess with the organisation of your runs: it will add mutliple entries to this list (and thus create confusion):

[image: tensorboard image]

I would recommend that instead you just do:

```
my_summary_writer.add_scalar(f'check_info/score',    score[iter],    iter)
my_summary_writer.add_scalar(f'check_info/score_nf', score_nf[iter], iter)
```

Comment: What does 'nf' stand for in your examples?

Comment: @BramVanroy It's a trading model, nf means "no fee", a calculation of the score without taking fees into account. It's specific to my use case, you can name your scalars whatever you want (loss, performance, my_param...)

Comment: @BenjaminCrouzier I'm trying your recommendation and it doesn't appear to be grouping scalar traces with the same prefix together into a single plot. Is there some trick to be aware of?

Comment: Same, the plots are placed next to each other horizontally, but are still separate with different tags.

Comment: I started with that before coming here, but the recommended approach in this answer is not the solution to the question asked here. I also wanted to do this in PyTorch, while preserving the clean folder structure. I posted my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62203250/5235274

Comment: Can someone please explain what's the reasoning behind "`add_scalars` [messing] with the organisation of your runs"? What do multiple runs have to do with multiple graphs in one?

Comment: Please explain the "instead" part. Doing this creates multiple figures instead of a single one with multiple plots.

Answer (score 27):

Here is a way to have **multiple graphs** in **one plot** grouped into **one single run**, using [add_custom_scalar](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensorboard.html#torch.utils.tensorboard.writer.SummaryWriter.add_custom_scalars) on [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/).

What I get:

[image]

The corresponding complete running code:

```
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
import math

layout = {
    "ABCDE": {
        "loss": ["Multiline", ["loss/train", "loss/validation"]],
        "accuracy": ["Multiline", ["accuracy/train", "accuracy/validation"]],
    },
}

writer = SummaryWriter()
writer.add_custom_scalars(layout)


epochs = 10
batch_size = 50

for epoch in range(epochs):
    for index in range(batch_size):
        global_batch_index = epoch * batch_size + index

        train_loss = math.exp(-0.01 * global_batch_index)
        train_accuracy = 1 - math.exp(-0.01 * global_batch_index)

        writer.add_scalar("loss/train", train_loss, global_batch_index)
        writer.add_scalar("accuracy/train", train_accuracy, global_batch_index)

    validation_loss = train_loss + 0.1
    validation_accuracy = train_accuracy - 0.1

    writer.add_scalar("loss/validation", validation_loss, global_batch_index)
    writer.add_scalar("accuracy/validation", validation_accuracy, global_batch_index)

 writer.close()
```

Please note the used tab on top left on the window is not `SCALARS` but `CUSTOM SCALARS`

Comment: This should be the accepted and most upvoted answer. Using a layout dictionary is clean, and makes exactly what OP asked.

Comment: Is there a way to have different colors for lines within the same plot (same run)? Having more than 2 gets messy

Comment: Did'n achieve to do that unfortunately...

Comment: @Gulzar Colors are associated to a specific run, so it is not possible https://stackoverflow.com/a/49090429/7059681

Answer (score 6):

- You can definitely plot scalars like the loss & validation accuracy : `tf.summary.scalar("loss", cost)` where cost is a tensor `cost = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y*tf.log(pred), reduction_indices=1))`
- Now you write summary for plotting all the values and then you may want to merge all these summary to a single summary by: `merged_summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()`
- Next step will be to run this summary in the session by `summary = sess.run(merged_summary_op)`
- After you run the `merged_summary_op` you have to write the summary using summary_writer : `summary_writer.add_summary(summary, epoch_number)` where `summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logs_path, graph=tf.get_default_graph())`
- Now open the terminal or cmd and run the following command: "Run the command `tensorboard --logdir="logpath"`
- Then open http://0.0.0.0:6006/ into your web browser
- You can refer the following link: https://github.com/jayshah19949596/Tensorboard-Visualization-Freezing-Graph
- Other things you can plot are the weights, inputs
- You can also display the images on tensorboard
- I think if you are using keras with tensorflow 1.5 then using tensorboard is easy because in tensorflow 1.5 keras is included as their official high level api
- I am sure you can plot different accuracy on the same graph for the same model with different hyper-paramters by using different FileWriter instances with different log path
- Check the image below:
  [image]
- I don't know if you can plot different accuracy of different models on the same graph... But you can write a program that does that
- May be you can write the summary information of different models to different directories and then point tensor-board to the parent directory to plot the accuracy of different models on the same graph as suggested in the comment by @RobertLugg

**==================== UPDATED =================**

I have tried saving accuracy and loss of different models to different directories and then making tensorboard to point to the parent directory and it works, you will get results of different models in the same graph. I have tried this myself and it works.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this answer doesn't explain how to place multiple values on a single chart.  It may be necessary to write summary information to individual subdirectories and point TensorBoard to the parent directory

Comment: Yes you are right @RobertLugg ... I included that in my answer... I forgot to show how you can plot different summary in the same plot

Comment: Please post code as code.

Answer (score 4):

Just save each runs in different folders under a main folder and open tensorboard on the main folder.

```
for i in range(x):
    tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir='./logs/' + 'run' + str(i), histogram_freq=0,
                                     write_graph=True, write_images=False)

    model.fit(X, Y, epochs=150, batch_size=10, callbacks=[tensorboard])
```

From the terminal, run tensorboard as such:

```
tensorboard --logdir=logs
```