# How to plot different summary metrics on the same plot with Tensorboard?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I would like to be able plot the **training loss per batch** and the ***average* validation loss** for the validation set on the same plot in Tensorboard. I ran into this issue when my validation set was too large to fit into memory so required batching and the use of `tf.metrics` update ops.

This question could apply to any Tensorflow metrics you wanted to appear on the same graph in Tensorboard.

I am able to

- plot these two graphs separately (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3fLM.png))
- plot the *validation-loss-per-validation-batch* on the same graph as the *training-loss-per-training-batch* (this was OK when the validation set could be a single batch and I could reuse the training summary op `train_summ` below)

In the example code below, my issue stems from the fact that my validation summary `tf.summary.scalar` with `name=loss` gets renamed to `loss_1` and thus is moved to a separate graph in Tensorboard. From what I can work out Tensorboard takes *"same name"* and plots them on the same graph, regardless of what folder they are in. This is frustrating as `train_summ` (name=loss) is only ever written to the `train` folder and `valid_summ` (name=loss) is only ever written to the `valid` folder - but is still renamed to `loss_1`.

The example code:

```
# View graphs with (Linux): $ tensorboard --logdir=/tmp/my_tf_model

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
import tempfile

def train_data_gen():
    yield np.random.normal(size=[3]), np.array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5])

def valid_data_gen():
    yield np.random.normal(size=[3]), np.array([0.8, 0.8, 0.8])

batch_size = 25
n_training_batches = 4
n_valid_batches = 2
n_epochs = 5
summary_loc = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), 'my_tf_model')
print("Summaries written to" + summary_loc)

# Dummy data
train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(train_data_gen, (tf.float32, tf.float32)).repeat().batch(batch_size)
valid_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(valid_data_gen, (tf.float32, tf.float32)).repeat().batch(batch_size)
handle = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[])
iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_string_handle(handle, 
train_data.output_types, train_data.output_shapes)
batch_x, batch_y = iterator.get_next()
train_iter = train_data.make_initializable_iterator()
valid_iter = valid_data.make_initializable_iterator()

# Some ops on the data
loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(batch_x, batch_y)
valid_loss, valid_loss_update = tf.metrics.mean(loss)

# Write to summaries
train_summ = tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss)
valid_summ = tf.summary.scalar('loss', valid_loss)  # <- will be renamed to "loss_1"

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    train_handle, valid_handle = sess.run([train_iter.string_handle(), valid_iter.string_handle()])
    sess.run([train_iter.initializer, valid_iter.initializer])

    # Summary writers
    writer_train = tf.summary.FileWriter(os.path.join(summary_loc, 'train'), sess.graph)
    writer_valid = tf.summary.FileWriter(os.path.join(summary_loc, 'valid'), sess.graph)

    global_step = 0  # implicit as no actual training
    for i in range(n_epochs):
        # "Training"
        for j in range(n_training_batches):
            global_step += 1
            summ = sess.run(train_summ, feed_dict={handle: train_handle})
            writer_train.add_summary(summary=summ, global_step=global_step)
        # "Validation"
        sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
        for j in range(n_valid_batches):
             _, batch_summ = sess.run([valid_loss_update, train_summ], feed_dict={handle: valid_handle})
            # The following will plot the batch loss for the validation set on the loss plot with the training data:
            # writer_valid.add_summary(summary=batch_summ, global_step=global_step + j + 1)
        summ = sess.run(valid_summ)
        writer_valid.add_summary(summary=summ, global_step=global_step)  # <- I want this on the training loss graph
```

### What I have tried

- Separate `tf.summary.FileWriter` objects (one for training, one for validation), as recommended by [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7089) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48951136/plot-multiple-graphs-in-one-plot-using-tensorboard?rq=1) (think what I'm after is alluded to in the comment of that question)
- The use of `tf.summary.merge` to merge all my training and validation/test metrics into overall summary ops; does useful book-keeping but doesn't plot what I want on the same graph
- Use of the `tf.summary.scalar` `family` attribute (`loss` still gets renamed to `loss_1`)
- **(Complete hack solution)** Use `valid_loss, valid_loss_update = tf.metrics.mean(loss)` on the *training* data and then run `tf.local_variables_initializer()` every training batch. This does give you the same summary op and thus puts things on the same graph but is surely not how you're *meant* to do this? It also doesn't generalise to other metrics.

### Context

- Tensorflow 1.9.0
- Tensorboard 1.9.0
- Python 3.5.2

Comment: see custom_scalar plugin for tensorboard

Comment: Thanks @Patwie I will try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Tensorboard `custom_scalar` plugin](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/tree/master/tensorboard/plugins/custom_scalar) is the way to solve this problem.

Here's the same example again with a `custom_scalar` to plot the two losses (per training batch + averaged over all validation batches) on the same plot:

```
# View graphs with (Linux): $ tensorboard --logdir=/tmp/my_tf_model

import os
import tempfile
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorboard import summary as summary_lib
from tensorboard.plugins.custom_scalar import layout_pb2

def train_data_gen():
    yield np.random.normal(size=[3]), np.array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5])

def valid_data_gen():
    yield np.random.normal(size=[3]), np.array([0.8, 0.8, 0.8])

batch_size = 25
n_training_batches = 4
n_valid_batches = 2
n_epochs = 5
summary_loc = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), 'my_tf_model')
print("Summaries written to " + summary_loc)

# Dummy data
train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    train_data_gen, (tf.float32, tf.float32)).repeat().batch(batch_size)
valid_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    valid_data_gen, (tf.float32, tf.float32)).repeat().batch(batch_size)
handle = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[])
iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_string_handle(handle, train_data.output_types,
                                               train_data.output_shapes)
batch_x, batch_y = iterator.get_next()
train_iter = train_data.make_initializable_iterator()
valid_iter = valid_data.make_initializable_iterator()

# Some ops on the data
loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(batch_x, batch_y)
valid_loss, valid_loss_update = tf.metrics.mean(loss)

with tf.name_scope('loss'):
    train_summ = summary_lib.scalar('training', loss)
    valid_summ = summary_lib.scalar('valid', valid_loss)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    train_handle, valid_handle = sess.run([train_iter.string_handle(), valid_iter.string_handle()])
    sess.run([train_iter.initializer, valid_iter.initializer])

    writer_train = tf.summary.FileWriter(os.path.join(summary_loc, 'train'), sess.graph)
    writer_valid = tf.summary.FileWriter(os.path.join(summary_loc, 'valid'), sess.graph)

    layout_summary = summary_lib.custom_scalar_pb(
        layout_pb2.Layout(category=[
            layout_pb2.Category(
                title='losses',
                chart=[
                    layout_pb2.Chart(
                        title='losses',
                        multiline=layout_pb2.MultilineChartContent(tag=[
                            'loss/training', 'loss/valid'
                        ]))
                ])
        ]))
    writer_train.add_summary(layout_summary)

    global_step = 0
    for i in range(n_epochs):
        for j in range(n_training_batches): # "Training"
            global_step += 1
            summ = sess.run(train_summ, feed_dict={handle: train_handle})
            writer_train.add_summary(summary=summ, global_step=global_step)

        sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
        for j in range(n_valid_batches):  # "Validation"
            _, batch_summ = sess.run([valid_loss_update, train_summ], feed_dict={handle: valid_handle})
        summ = sess.run(valid_summ)
        writer_valid.add_summary(summary=summ, global_step=global_step)
```

[Here's the resulting output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ee1ky.png) in Tensorboard.