# Tensorflow Object Detection API - showing loss for training and validation on one graph

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I am playing with [Tensorflow Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) and training the Faster R-CNN network on my own dataset. I am checking the progress of learning at Tensorbord. All metrics are there, but is there a way to have both loss plots, for training and validation data, on one graph? Or do I have to dive into TOD Api code and modify it? I would like to avoid the second because during every update of the API I will have to keep in mind that some of the code is changed locally.

[image: Loss plot]

Answer (score 1):

The underlying data for the plots is saved under different tag names (`loss` vs `loss_1`). I believe TensorBoard does not natively support displaying different tags in one plot. There might be third-party extensions to do this.

If different models used the same tag, the graphs would be combined by default (see: [Plot multiple graphs in one plot using Tensorboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48951136/plot-multiple-graphs-in-one-plot-using-tensorboard)).